# How to browser multiple file with paperclip in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have three field

```
a) email
b) phone number
c) browse files (Here one link `add more file`)
```

When user click on `add more file` link then one more browse button appear and so on

I want to save all files when user click on submit button

How Can I do that with `paperclip in rails 4`

Model

> User.rb

```
has_many invoices
accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoices, :allow_destroy => true
```

> Invoice.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

I have use field_for for invoice in view

controller

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.invoices.build
end

def create
  User.create(user_params)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your current setup will work well for one file, however if you want to add multiple files, you'll need to build the objects again & load a new `fields_for` to support that. To do this, I would recommend using Ajax:

---

I don't know if this will work, but this is how I would tackle the problem:

1. Put your `fields_for` into a partial
2. On your form, include "+" button with `:remote => :true`
3. Controller will handle AJAX request & build a new object
4. On successful AJAX request, load a partial with new `fields_for`
5. See if the submit includes all the files

---

**Create `fields_for` Partial**

Your form will likely look like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :invoices do |field| %>
    <%= field.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

You need to turn this into a partial:

```
<%= f.fields_for :invoices do |field| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'images_fields', locals: {f: field} %>
<% end %>
```

Your partial could then look like:

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

---

**Include "+" Button On Your Form**

On your form, you can just create a link like this:

```
<%= link_to "+", your_controller_action, :remote => :true %>
```

---

**Controller Will Handle Ajax Request**

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.invoices.build

  respond_to do |format|
      format.js { @user.invoices.build }
      format.html 
  end
end
```

This should render a new object, which you can then append to the form with the returned JS:

```
#app/views/controller/new.js.erb
$("form").append("<%=j render :partial => 'images_fields', locals: {f: @user} %>")
```

---

**See If It Submits All The Files**

My code probably won't work as it needs debugging. However, this is the process I would use. If you try it, we can debug in the comments

Let me know how it goes!!